# my facebook app not working android 2.1

Tags: android, facebook

I am using Facebook sdk in my application for getting user profile information like name,profile picture URL. its work in all emulators that are above android 2.2 but not working in android 2.1 .and i am not getting status of the user.please help me how to get status information.please can anyone help me.

Comment: Show logcat output or explain what kind of exception occurs when you launch the application?

Comment: Did you try to use FQL ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to have the Android 2.2 (API 8) components installed in order to use the Facebook SDK. Meaning it wont work below Android 2.2
Source = [Facebook SDK for Android](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/)